# jQuery how many th hasClass

Tags: jquery, html-table

I need to find out how many th have the class 'ui-tableFilter-filtered';

I tried the following

```
updatecounter(table.find("th").hasClass('ui-tableFilter-filtered'));
```

but nothing is returned

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('th.ui-tableFilter-filtered').length
```

Comment: I think you want `$('th.ui-tableFilter-filtered').length` (no space between `th` and `.ui-...`).  You can also use `.size()` instead of `.length`.

Comment: This worked, but it kept showing 11, even when less then 11 or more then 11

Comment: Paste the HTML you are using into your question.